# Elasticsearch: same request, different results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am requesting ES against an index with 22 millions of records using python. I just try to have an extract month by month.

I can have 10000 records for one request, and then 5 seconds later I request again and I have 20000+ records and then again an again until 60000+ which is the correct result.

Sometimes I have the correct answer immediately, sometimes only after the 10th request.

My theory is the index is destructed and rebuild, and I request again it during the rebuild.

```
{"_source": {"includes": grabFields},
            "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter":
                        [
                            {"range": {"RECEPTION_TIME": {"gte": "1554076800000","lte": "1556668799000"}}}
                        ]
                    ,
                "must": [{
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [{
                            "match": {
                                "COLOR": "BLUE"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "match": {
                                "COLOR": "RED"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "match": {
                                "COLOR": "ROSE"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "match": {
                                "COLOR": "GREEN"
                            },
                        }]
                    }
                }, {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [{
                            "match": {
                                "CLASS": "FIRST"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "match": {
                                "CLASS": "SECOND"
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [{
                            "match": {
                                "IGNORE_ME": "YES"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share your search query in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch allow a near real-time search experience. There is a slight delay between the moment you index a document and the moment it is available for search.

This delay is configured by the `refresh_interval` setting of your index. There is also an API to trigger the refresh operation that makes documents availables for search. ( [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-refresh.html)  )

Could you check your index refresh_interval ?

Comment: but this is a huge difference and doesn't seem OP has changed the `refresh_interval`